# Android studio start up jdk error

Tags: android, startup

Android studio I have a startup error jdk  and got the JDK x64 and installation program files x86 but I still get the error and I set of the variables right as you see in the image and I still get to start up error

the error
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOkzX.jpg)
the setting
[the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHUEi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are running the wrong executable. If you are on a 64-bit system run the 64-bit executable. If you are on a 32-bit system, use the 32-bit JDK and executable.

Comment: i download and install the jdk x64 and how to run x64 instead of 32

Comment: and also when i open studio64 i get this error in photo